# How to pass runtime arguments in OpenScript - Oracle Application Testing Suite?

Tags: java, oracle, runtime, openscript

I need to know how to pass dynamic runtime arguments in an OpenScript script. I tried doing the same by passing a value in VMArguments in Run Configuration as `-DtxnID=7002` and used the `VUserSettings` object to get the same but was not able to do so as I always get a `null` value :

```
VUserSettings settings = null;
settings = getSettings();
System.out.println(settings.get("txnID")); // prints null
```

I need to do the same in Oracle Load Testing while the script is invoked by the VUs (Virtual Users).

Answer (score 0):

I used system properties to read system arguments from within the script.

Try the following for instance:

```
System.getProperty("txnID");
```

Answer (score 0):

[OpenScript Install Dir]/runScript.bat  (on windows, linux simialr), the runScript can be used to run script,

use special para need to set in format " -key1 value1 -key2 value2 .... ",  in the script use "getSettings().get("key"))"